# Why does angular-cli put new project in the parent directory?

Tags: angular-cli

I don't understand why `ng new` is putting the new project in the parent of the current directory instead of putting it in the current directory.

```
[12:05:59] angular-cli
// ♥ pwd
/Users/Dan/work/angular-cli
[12:06:06] angular-cli
// ♥ ng new ang-cli-1
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
installing ng2
  create .clang-format
  create .editorconfig
  create src/app/ang-cli-1.component.css
  create src/app/ang-cli-1.component.html
  create src/app/ang-cli-1.component.spec.ts
  create src/app/ang-cli-1.component.ts
  create src/app/environment.ts
  create src/app/index.ts
  create src/app/shared/index.ts
  create src/favicon.ico
  create src/index.html
  create src/main.ts
  create src/system-config.ts
  create src/tsconfig.json
  create src/typings.d.ts
  create angular-cli-build.js
  create angular-cli.json
  create config/environment.dev.ts
  create config/environment.js
  create config/environment.prod.ts
  create config/karma-test-shim.js
  create config/karma.conf.js
  create config/protractor.conf.js
  create e2e/app.e2e.ts
  create e2e/app.po.ts
  create e2e/tsconfig.json
  create e2e/typings.d.ts
  create .gitignore
  create package.json
  create public/.npmignore
  create tslint.json
  create typings.json
Successfully initialized git.
⠋ Installing packages for tooling via npm
├── es6-shim (ambient)
├── angular-protractor (ambient dev)
├── jasmine (ambient dev)
└── selenium-webdriver (ambient dev)

Installed packages for tooling via npm.
[12:08:00] angular-cli
// ♥ ls
[12:08:20] angular-cli
// ♥ ls ../ang-cli-1/
angular-cli-build.js    node_modules        tslint.json
angular-cli.json    package.json        typings
config          public          typings.json
e2e         src
[12:08:38] angular-cli
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have a `package.json` file in your home/user directory?  I experienced this issue, then I removed `package.json` and that stopped it.

I believe that angular cli looks for a package.json file, beginning in the current directory, then navigating up the directory tree until it reaches your home/user directory.  It stops at the first `package.json` it finds and performs the command there.  If it doesn't find a `package.json` file, it performs the command from the current directory.

The current version of angular-cli now returns the error `You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project` when there is a `package.json` file in a parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was building an app within an app and could not remove the outer package.JSON file. I created an apps folder inside the outer project and navigated inside it. Once there I ran NPM INIT and created a simple empty package.JSON file then ran the ng new command and it worked well.

Answer (score -1):

Removing package.json file from parent directory solve problem for me.

Comment: This answer is simply repeating what was said in the accepted answer